Problem with updating Realm Object using Objects DAO in Swift
Hi guys i have a specific problem with updating realm object. I have an object ToDo which have properties and ToDoDAO:
public struct ToDo: LocalStorable {
    public let id: String
    public let name: String
    public var symbol: Icon
    public let image: Data?
    public let executedDate: Date
    public let executedTime: Date
    public let remindTime: Date?
    public let reminderRepetition: Repetition
    public let tag: String
    public var subtasks: [SubToDo]
    public let isArchived: Bool
    public var isDone: Bool
    
    public init(
        id: String = UUID().uuidString,
        name: String,
        symbol: Icon,
        image: Data?,
        executedDate: Date,
        executedTime: Date,
        remindTime: Date?,
        reminderRepetition: Repetition,
        tag: String,
        subtasks: [SubToDo],
        isArchived: Bool = false,
        isDone: Bool = false
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.image = image
        self.executedDate = executedDate
        self.executedTime = executedTime
        self.remindTime = remindTime
        self.reminderRepetition = reminderRepetition
        self.tag = tag
        self.subtasks = subtasks
        self.isArchived = isArchived
        self.isDone = isDone
    }
    
    public init(task: ToDo, isDone: Bool) {
        self.id = task.id
        self.name = task.name
        self.symbol = task.symbol
        self.image = task.image
        self.executedDate = task.executedDate
        self.executedTime = task.executedTime
        self.remindTime = task.remindTime
        self.reminderRepetition = task.reminderRepetition
        self.tag = task.tag
        self.subtasks = task.subtasks
        self.isArchived = task.isArchived
        self.isDone = isDone
    }
    
    public init(from dao: ToDoDAO) {
        self.id = dao.id
        self.name = dao.name
        if let iconDAO = dao.symbol {
            print("DEBUG - ToDo iconDAO:", iconDAO)
            self.symbol = Icon(from: iconDAO)
        } else {
            print("DEBUG - ToDo fail")
            self.symbol = .clipboardIcon
        }
        self.image = dao.image
        self.executedDate = dao.executedDate
        self.executedTime = dao.executedTime
        self.remindTime = dao.remindTime
        self.reminderRepetition = Repetition(rawValue: dao.reminderRepetition ?? "") ?? .daily
        self.tag = dao.tag
        self.subtasks = dao.subtasks.map { SubToDo(from: $0) }
        self.isArchived = dao.isArchived
        self.isDone = dao.isDone
    }
    
    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case symbol
        case image
        case executedDate
        case executedTime
        case remindTime
        case reminderRepetition
        case tag
        case subtasks
        case isArchived
        case isDone
    }
}

This is ToDoDAO:
public final class ToDoDAO: RealmSwift.Object, LocalDAOInterface {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) public var id: String
    @Persisted public var name: String
    @Persisted public var symbol: IconDAO?
    @Persisted public var image: Data?
    @Persisted public var executedDate: Date
    @Persisted public var executedTime: Date
    @Persisted public var remindTime: Date?
    @Persisted public var reminderRepetition: String
    @Persisted public var tag: String
    @Persisted public var subtasks: RealmSwift.List<SubToDoDAO>
    @Persisted public var isArchived: Bool
    @Persisted public var isDone: Bool
    
    override public init() {
        super.init()
        self.name = ""
        self.symbol = IconDAO()
        self.image = Data()
        self.executedDate = Date()
        self.executedTime = Date()
        self.remindTime = nil
        self.reminderRepetition = ""
        self.tag = Tag.otherEvent.rawValue
        self.subtasks = RealmSwift.List<SubToDoDAO>()
        self.isArchived = false
        self.isDone = false
    }
    
    public init(from todo: ToDo) {
        super.init()
        self.id = todo.id
        self.name = todo.name
        self.symbol = IconDAO(from: todo.symbol)
        self.image = todo.image
        self.executedDate = todo.executedDate
        self.executedTime = todo.executedTime
        self.remindTime = todo.remindTime
        self.reminderRepetition = todo.reminderRepetition.rawValue
        self.tag = todo.tag
        self.subtasks.append(objectsIn: todo.subtasks.map { SubToDoDAO(from: $0) })
        self.isArchived = todo.isArchived
        self.isDone = todo.isDone
    }
}

and i cannot update two properies: symbol and subtasks and this is Icon model:
public struct Icon: LocalStorable {
    public let id: String
    public let symbol: Data
    public let circleColor: Color

    public init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, symbol: Data, circleColor: Color) {
        self.id = id
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.circleColor = circleColor
    }
    
    public init(from dao: IconDAO) {
        self.id = dao.id
        self.symbol = dao.symbol
        self.circleColor = Color(hex: dao.circleColor) ?? .accentColor
    }
    
    public init(icon: Icon) {
        self.id = icon.id
        self.symbol = icon.symbol
        self.circleColor = icon.circleColor
    }
    
    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case symbol
        case circleColor
    }

    public static let tapIcon       = Icon(symbol: Icons.tap?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .blue.opacity(0.2))
    public static let dishIcon      = Icon(symbol: Icons.dinner?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .brown)
    public static let trayIcon      = Icon(symbol: Icons.tray?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .blue.opacity(0.2))
    public static let clipboardIcon = Icon(symbol: Icons.clipboard?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .yellow)
    public static let photoIcon     = Icon(symbol: Icons.photo?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .blue.opacity(0.1))
    public static let birthdayIcon  = Icon(symbol: Icons.birthday?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .yellow.opacity(0.5))
    public static let catIcon       = Icon(symbol: Icons.cat?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .green.opacity(0.6))
    public static let cinemaIcon    = Icon(symbol: Icons.cinema?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .red.opacity(0.5))
    public static let dentist       = Icon(symbol: Icons.dentist?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .green.opacity(0.7))
    public static let dog           = Icon(symbol: Icons.dog?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .yellow.opacity(0.7))
    public static let football      = Icon(symbol: Icons.football?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .purple.opacity(0.4))
    public static let learning      = Icon(symbol: Icons.learning?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .blue.opacity(0.4))
    public static let roadTrip      = Icon(symbol: Icons.roadTrip?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .red.opacity(0.3))
    public static let running       = Icon(symbol: Icons.running?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .red.opacity(0.4))
    public static let shopping      = Icon(symbol: Icons.shopping?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .yellow.opacity(0.5))
    public static let vacation      = Icon(symbol: Icons.vacation?.pngData() ?? Data(), circleColor: .orange.opacity(0.6))
    
    public static let allIcons: [Icon] = [
        dishIcon,
        clipboardIcon,
        birthdayIcon,
        catIcon,
        cinemaIcon,
        dentist,
        dog,
        football,
        learning,
        roadTrip,
        running,
        shopping,
        vacation
    ]
}

and IconDAO:
public final class IconDAO: RealmSwift.Object, LocalDAOInterface {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) public var id: String
    @Persisted public var symbol: Data
    @Persisted public var circleColor: String
    
    override public init() {
        super.init()
        self.symbol = Data()
        self.circleColor = ""
    }
    
    public init(from icon: Icon) {
        super.init()
        self.id = icon.id
        self.symbol = icon.symbol
        self.circleColor = icon.circleColor.toHex() ?? ""
    }
}

and also SubToDo:
public struct SubToDo: LocalStorable {
    public let id: String
    public var title: String
    public var isCompleted: Bool
    
    public init(
        id: String = UUID().uuidString,
        title: String,
        isCompleted: Bool = false
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
    }
    
    public init(from dao: SubToDoDAO) {
        self.id = dao.id
        self.title = dao.title
        self.isCompleted = dao.isCompleted
    }
    
    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case isCompleted
    }
}

and DAO:
public final class SubToDoDAO: RealmSwift.Object, LocalDAOInterface {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) public var id: String
    @Persisted public var title: String
    @Persisted public var isCompleted: Bool
    
    override public init() {
        super.init()
        self.title = ""
        self.isCompleted = false
    }
    
    public init(from subtodo: SubToDo) {
        super.init()
        self.id = subtodo.id
        self.title = subtodo.title
        self.isCompleted = subtodo.isCompleted
    }
}

i try to update it using func below but it didn't work, for example updating ICON: ToDo gets deafult value which is .clipboardIcon and in Realm Studio it's display nil.

Update ToDo


    func updateToDo(toDo: ToDo) async throws {
            state = .loading
            
            var updatedToDo = ToDo(
                id: toDo.id,
                name: newTaskTitle,
                symbol: newTaskSymbol,
                image: selectedTaskImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9),
                executedDate: taskDay,
                executedTime: taskTime,
                remindTime: remindTime,
                reminderRepetition: repetition,
                tag: tag.rawValue,
                subtasks: subtasks
            )
            
            print("DEBUG - todo: ", toDo.symbol)
            print("DEBUG - updatedToDo: ", updatedToDo.symbol)
            
            let updates = compare(old: toDo, updated: updatedToDo)
            
            try await toDoManager.updateToDo(todo: toDo, data: updates)
            
            state = .loaded
        }


this is also compare func:

    public func compare(old: any LocalStorable, updated: any LocalStorable) -> [String: Any] {
        var differences: [String: Any] = [:]
    
        let oldMirror = Mirror(reflecting: old)
        let newMirror = Mirror(reflecting: updated)
    
        for (propertyName, oldValue) in oldMirror.children {
            guard let propertyName else { continue }
    
            if let newValue = newMirror.descendant(propertyName) {
                if let oldEnumValue = oldValue as? (any RawRepresentable),
                   let newEnumValue = newValue as? (any RawRepresentable),
                   "\(oldEnumValue.rawValue)" != "\(newEnumValue.rawValue)" {
                    differences[propertyName] = newEnumValue.rawValue
                } else if "\(oldValue)" != "\(newValue)" {
                    differences[propertyName] = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    
        return differences
    }


the fun fact is that when i create a ToDo everything works fine.
Create ToDo
func createToDo() async throws {
        state = .loading
        
        let newToDo = ToDo(
            name: newTaskTitle,
            symbol: newTaskSymbol,
            image: selectedTaskImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9),
            executedDate: taskDay,
            executedTime: taskTime,
            remindTime: remindTime,
            reminderRepetition: repetition,
            tag: tag.rawValue,
            subtasks: subtasks
        )
        
        try await toDoManager.createToDo(todo: newToDo)
        
        state = .loaded
    }

this is also viewModel where i have functions:
View Model
@MainActor
final class AddTaskViewModel: ObservableObject {
    enum State: Equatable {
        case loading
        case loaded
        case error(String)
    }
    
    @Published private(set) var state: State = .loaded
    @Published private(set) var showDivider: Bool = true
    @Published private(set) var selectedPicker: Picker?
    @Published private(set) var selectedTaskImage: UIImage? = nil
    @Published var newTaskTitle: String = ""
    @Published var isScrolled: Bool = false
    @Published var newTaskSymbol: Icon = .clipboardIcon
    @Published var taskDay: Date = .now
    @Published var taskTime: Date = .now
    @Published var remindTime: Date?
    @Published var repetition: Repetition = .noRepeat
    @Published var tag: Tag = .all
    @Published var newSubtaskTitle: String = ""
    @Published var editSubtaskTextFieldText: String = ""
    @Published var editingSubtaskIndex: Int? = nil
    @Published var subtasks: [SubToDo] = []
    @Published var defaultScrollAnchor: UnitPoint? = .top
    @Published var taskImageSelection: PhotosPickerItem? = nil {
        didSet {
            Task {
                do {
                    try await setImage(from: taskImageSelection)
                } catch {
                    handleError(error: error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //TODO: add validation to newTaskTitle
   
    @Inject private var toDoManager: ToDoManagerInterface
    
    private var existingToDo: ToDo?
    
    private var isEditing: Binding<Bool?>
    
    var buttonTitle: LocalizedStringKey {
        existingToDo == nil ? "Create Task" : "Update Task"
    }
    
    var isPickerSelected: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding<Bool>(
            get: {
                self.selectedPicker != nil },
            set: {
                if !$0 {
                    self.selectedPicker = nil
                }
            }
        )
    }
    
    var selectedDate: String { taskDay.isToday ? "Today" : dateFormatter(dateFormat: .dateWithDots).string(from: taskDay) }
    
    var selectedTime: String { "Time: \(dateFormatter(dateFormat: .time).string(from: taskTime))" }
    
    var selectedReminder: String { remindTime != nil ? dateFormatter(dateFormat: .timeWithPeriods).string(from: remindTime ?? Date()) : "No reminder" }
    
    init(isEditing: Binding<Bool?> = .constant(nil)) {
        if let toDo = existingToDo {
            self.existingToDo = toDo
            self.newTaskTitle = toDo.name
            self.newTaskSymbol = toDo.symbol
            self.taskDay = toDo.executedDate
            self.taskTime = toDo.executedTime
            self.remindTime = toDo.remindTime
            self.repetition = toDo.reminderRepetition
            if let tag = Tag(rawValue: toDo.tag) {
                self.tag = tag
            }
            self.subtasks = toDo.subtasks
            self.selectedTaskImage = toDo.image.flatMap { UIImage(data: $0) }
        }
        
        self.isEditing = isEditing
    }
    
    func handleScrollActions(position: Double) {
        showDivider = position >= -80.0
        isScrolled = position < -10
    }
    
     func onPickerSelected(picker: Picker?) {
         if let index = editingSubtaskIndex, selectedPicker == .editSubtask {
             subtasks[index].title = editSubtaskTextFieldText
         }
         
         if picker == .subtask {
            createSubtask()
             print("DEBUG - created Subtask:", subtasks)
        }
        
        onShowOptionToggle()
    }
    
    private func onShowOptionToggle() {
        withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.1)) {
            selectedPicker = nil
        }
    }
    
    func handlePickerSelection(_ picker: Picker, subtaskIndex: Int? = nil) {
        withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 0.7)) {
            selectedPicker = picker
            
            if let index = subtaskIndex {
                editingSubtaskIndex = index
                editSubtaskTextFieldText = subtasks[index].title
            }
        }
    }
    
    typealias Picker = ToDoInterface.Picker
}

extension AddTaskViewModel {
    private func setImage(from selection: PhotosPickerItem?) async throws {
        guard let selection else { return }
        
        let data = try await selection.loadTransferable(type: Data.self)
        
        guard let data, let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
            throw AppError.unableToLoadImage
        }
        
        selectedTaskImage = uiImage
    }
    
    func createToDo() async throws {
        state = .loading
        
        let newToDo = ToDo(
            name: newTaskTitle,
            symbol: newTaskSymbol,
            image: selectedTaskImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9),
            executedDate: taskDay,
            executedTime: taskTime,
            remindTime: remindTime,
            reminderRepetition: repetition,
            tag: tag.rawValue,
            subtasks: subtasks
        )
        
        try await toDoManager.createToDo(todo: newToDo)
        
        state = .loaded
    }
    
    func handleError(error: Error) {
        withAnimation {
            if let localizedError = error as? LocalizedError {
                state = .error(localizedError.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                state = .error(AppError.unexpectedError(error.localizedDescription).errorDescription ?? error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func handleDismissErrorView() {
        withAnimation {
            state = .loaded
        }
    }
    
    private func createSubtask() {
        guard !newSubtaskTitle.isEmpty else { return }
        
        let newSubtask = SubToDo(title: newSubtaskTitle)
        
        subtasks.append(newSubtask)
        
        newSubtaskTitle = ""
    }
}

//MARK: Task Management
extension AddTaskViewModel {
    func manageToDo() async throws {
        if let existingToDo = existingToDo {
            try await updateToDo(toDo: existingToDo)
            isEditing.wrappedValue = false
        } else {
            try await createToDo()
        }
    }
    
    func updateToDo(toDo: ToDo) async throws {
        state = .loading
        
        var updatedToDo = ToDo(
            id: toDo.id,
            name: newTaskTitle,
            symbol: newTaskSymbol,
            image: selectedTaskImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9),
            executedDate: taskDay,
            executedTime: taskTime,
            remindTime: remindTime,
            reminderRepetition: repetition,
            tag: tag.rawValue,
            subtasks: subtasks
        )
        
        print("DEBUG - todo: ", toDo.symbol)
        print("DEBUG - updatedToDo: ", updatedToDo.symbol)
        
        let updates = compare(old: toDo, updated: updatedToDo)
        
        try await toDoManager.updateToDo(todo: toDo, data: updates)
        
        state = .loaded
    }
    
    func readActiveToDo(primaryKey: String) async throws {
        self.existingToDo = try await toDoManager.readToDo(primaryKey: primaryKey)
        print("DEBUG - read todo:", existingToDo)
    }
}

If anyone have a idea why is this not working please help me...
Maybe I created the objects incorrectly and that's why updating doesn't work, but the question is why adding ToDo works.

We may be able to help but that is way too much code to parse through, trying to figure out what object relationships are etc. Update the question with abbreviated Realm models and the minimal code to duplicate the issue. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. We also don't know what toDoManager does so that could be the issue. ToDo is not a Realm object so how is it "working" and play a role?

One day reset and i finally got an idea how to handle with this problem any successfully solve it! :)
